# Contact form 7 plugin customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

In my contact form 7, I am using pipe system, but I want to save email address into other filed also so how can I get this any help, for example, email value come to this shortcode [email] I need to save this value [email1]

Drop down code:

```
[select* email-recipient include_blank "ECommerce Development|test@gmail.com" "Web Development|test@gmail.com" "Mobile Application Development|test@gmail.com" "Digital marketing|test@gmail.com" "IOT|test@gmail.com" "Chatbot|test@gmail.com"]
```

input value:   `[hidden hidden-701 "Pipe email"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set id attribute in select drop down of contact form 7 like

```
[select* email-recipient include_blank "ECommerce Development|harshk.magneto@gmail.com" "Web Development|harshk.magneto@gmail.com" "Mobile Application Development|harshk.magneto@gmail.com" "Digital marketing|harshk.magneto@gmail.com" "IOT|harshk.magneto@gmail.com" "Chatbot|harshk.magneto@gmail.com" id:email-recipientemail-recipient]
```

Go to your theme's footer.php file [i.e. wp-content\themes\themename] and add below code.

```
<?php if(is_page(ID)) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery(document).on('change', '#email-recipient', function(){                
                jQuery("input[name=hidden-701]").val(jQuery('select#email-recipient option:selected').val());
            });
        }); 
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Where ID is page id where you include this contact form.

Comment: No its not Working Simple field name print in mail.

Comment: Can i know how you display field in mail body?

Comment: Can you please suggest me how can i pass contact form field short code in other field like [your-name] code to any hidden field in contact form field